# Why is this estimator with ill-defined moments useful? And why is the Cauchy PV of its expectation integral a reasonable measure of center?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, cauchy-principal-value

This question pertains to the paper (available online through [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332914)):

> M. H. QUENOUILLE, NOTES ON BIAS IN ESTIMATION, Biometrika, Volume 43,
> Issue 3-4, December 1956, Pages 353–360,
> https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/43.3-4.353

In particular I am interested in the following example given in section 6:

[image]

In this example $t_n$ is the maximum likelihood estimator for $1/\mu$, $t_n^\prime$ is a reduced bias estimator for $1/\mu$ using the proposed jackknife method, and the data is distributed according to $x_i\sim\mathcal N(2,1)$. The point of the example was to show the estimator $t_n^\prime$ is able to estimate $1/\mu$ with less "bias" than $t_n$.

**Observation:**

The estimator $t_n$ can be written as $t_n=1/\bar X_n$ with $\bar X_n\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$.  It can easily be shown that $E(t_n)$ is undefined because the integral $E(t_n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{-1}\phi(x,\mu,\sigma^2/n)\,\mathrm dx$ diverges. Therefore $t_n$ (and $t_n^\prime$) have no expected value and thus one cannot really talk about their biases.

**Questions:**

1. Given that $E(t_n)$ is undefined, why is $t_n$ a useful estimator of $1/\mu$? Without a well-defined expected value, does $t_n$ actually estimate anything?
2. The author does assign a value to $E(t_n)$ in terms of the Cauchy principal value (see bottom of page). Why is the Cauchy principal value a useful measure of center for $t_n$?

Comment: Usually one considers an estimator useful if it converges to the "real value of the parameter" (in some sense). If $\bar x \to \mu \neq 0,$ then $1/\bar x \to 1/\mu,$ and everything is good. Of course, you will not be able to measure "spread." Maybe then you can consider something like (assuming $\mu > 0$), $\bar x < \varepsilon$ and $\bar x > \varepsilon,$ the first set will be small in probability while the second one will be large, you can therefore ignore the first term if you want to calculate the spread of the estimator. In fact, this "cut-off" technique is how one usually proves the LLN

Comment: The Cauchy principal value is the expectation over sets $|t_n| < L,$ but this will be equivalent to $|\bar x| > \frac{1}{L},$ which again, is the most sensible thing to do in my humble opinion. Note that $t_n$ has no expectation because it blows off in an infinitesimally small-probability set, yet, in all practical purposes, this will not occur...

Comment: (I read this in Feller's first book. In applications of the normal distribution to human height, we never bother with the fact that there is a positive probability assigned to the negative number mainly because if a new human were born every second, one would need to repeat the universe many times over and again before the expected number of humans with negative height becomes an integer. Our brains are not well-adapted to understand inutively either very big or very tiny quantities.)

Comment: @WilliamM.  In the human height example, I get there are errors induced by assuming a normal model; however, human heights are always strictly positive and so the statistic $1/\bar X_n$ is going to be well-behaved...furthermore, it should agree with the CPV.  But in the case where the data is actually from a normal population shouldn't we expect to eventually see positive and negative events?...(1/2)

Comment: @WilliamM. (2/2)...In such cases $1/\bar X_n$ in theory should never converge.  In practice, however, it would seem that we don't observe data out in the extreme tails of the distribution and so if the mean is relatively large in comparison to the std. dev. then we only observe all poisitive or all negative data and $1/\bar X_n$ ends up agreeing with the CPV..just trying to figure out how to explain this in my own words...